# Which one performs better than the other? ui-sref or href?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am making server side rendering for a big data. Than I send the rendered html to angular to compile it. On some `<a>` elements, I use `ui-sref` directive and as angular compile it, generate a `href` attr.

If I define the attr by myself to render on the server side, can I get more performance compared to the other?

Comment: Why not try both and see what happens in the browser console under the network section? I doubt you can squeeze much performance out of it anyway, it's just a function that renders some html from input.

Comment: ui-sref is generated on the client and href is generated on the server, so it's not meaningful to compare their performances. If you use href, the performance improves 100% on the client, if you use ui-sref, the performance improves 100% on the server. That said, in practice you'll probably save only fractions of milliseconds so performance shouldn't be the deciding factor here.

Comment: I want to improve client performance, so I think, will use href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using href will be always have a better performance because angular doesn't have to process it (read the directive and execute the code inside it)

On the other hand the you have the benefits of using ui-sref, and one of the reason to use it, it's to name your state and then in state definition match it against a url, so if you later on decide to change your state url you just do it in one place.